# Direct Limit of finitely generated groups

Tags: group-theory

Is every group the direct limit of its finitely generated subgroups? This is true for abelian groups, I have not seen this statement for nonabelian groups, so i am wondering if this is true. Seems like the same proof should go through.

Comment: Did you try to write things down? Did you find any obstruction in the proof?

Comment: NO, i did not find any obstruction, that is why i posted this as a question because I have not found this statement in some textbook, so wondered if i did something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is a general feature of categories of models of [Lawvere theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawvere_theory): e.g. every ring is the filtered colimit ("direct limit" is a terrible word, since it doesn't describe a limit) of its finitely generated subrings, and so forth. The key unifying observation is that a function $f : X \to Y$ between models (groups, rings, etc.) is a homomorphism iff it's a homomorphism when restricted to finitely generated submodels of $X$, since all the conditions that $f$ needs to satisfy only involve finitely many elements of $X$ at a time.

In fact we can say something a bit stronger: it turns out that every model (group, ring, etc.) is a filtered colimit of finitely presented, not just finitely generated, models. See [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/04/25/compact-objects/) for a discussion.

Comment: THanks, good to know this. I dont know why standard texts dont include this, so i thought maybe there was something wrong in my proof which i missed.

Comment: @user114539: it doesn't have any particularly elementary applications that I know of, so I don't see why they would.

Comment: still it is a nice result which comes for free, so a mention would not harm anyone, but i understand what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: @user114539: mentioning a result you don't plan on using can be confusing to students. There's value in staying focused.